# Python: Fast and minimalistic way to zip and pair matching elements in two lists

Tags: python

I have:

```
>>> As = [1, 2, 5, 6]
>>> Bs = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want something like `zip_fn` below:

```
>>> Rs = zip_fn(As, Bs, cmp)
>>> Rs
[(1, None), (2, 2), (None, 3), (None, 4), (5, 5), (6, None)]
```

In other words, given two arbitrary sequences `As` and `Bs`, I want to produce a list of tuples `Rs` such that choices that satisfy `cmp(a, b) == 0` are paired together into their own tuple `(a, b)`, but those in `As` and `Bs` without matching counterparts are output as `(a, None)` and `(None, b)` respectively.

Some points:

- I'm not worried about duplicates in `As` or `Bs` as there won't be any.
- `Rs` can be an iterator that produces the same sequence.
- The ordering of `Rs` is unimportant.

I've already implemented something that satisfies the functional requirement using straight-forward presorted looping but it's roughly 30 lines.  I'm looking for something that makes better use of builtins or `itertools`esque libraries for shorter code and faster (C native) running.

**Edit:**

I should have made this clearer.  Although I used a list of plain numbers in the example above for brevity, the elements I'm actually working with are tuples, and `cmp` tests only a part of the tuple for equality.  It might be easier to think of the elements as being *records* and `cmp` as something that matches on the *key fields*.  I could wrap the elements in a class and make it hashable on the key, but such a set up isn't required for anything else so any solution that requires this will get this as additional code and runtime overhead.

Summarizing this as additional points to the some above:

- It's vital that `cmp` is used for comparison as it's not a test for basic equality.
- In the result `[(a, b)]`, `a` should be the same instance as one of the elements in `As` and `b` the same instance of one of the elements in `Bs`, provided they aren't `None`.
- Elements in `As` and `Bs` aren't hashable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with something like @thg435's answer and use <strike>`deque`</strike> *(edit: changed to* `list` *as pointed out by @EOL)*, which has helped me cut back on a lot of code in what I originally had.

I chose this for these reasons:

- The time complexity calculation is simplistic and rather easy to predict.
- It didn't require changing the interface.
- I felt there was a good balance between the amount of code and expected runtime efficiency.

Implementation follows:

```
def izip_pairs(xs, ys, cmp):
    xs = list(reversed(sorted(xs, cmp)))
    ys = list(reversed(sorted(ys, cmp)))

    while xs or ys:
        delta = ((not xs) - (not ys)) or cmp(xs[-1], ys[-1])

        x = xs.pop() if delta <= 0 else None
        y = ys.pop() if delta >= 0 else None
        yield x, y
```

**For comparison's sake:**

Inspired by everyone's set-based answers, and for comparison's sake, I've changed the interface to accommodate and implemented a hash-lookup based solution.

```
def izip_keys(xs, ys, key):
    xs = {key(x): x for x in xs}
    ys = {key(y): y for y in ys}

    for k in set(xs.keys() + ys.keys()):
        yield xs.get(k, None), ys.get(k, None)
```

**Time difference:**

My conclusion on the results below is that looping on sorted lists scales much better for larger number of elements, while hash-lookup is only faster for tiny *Ns*.

```
>>> xs = range(100, 200)
>>> ys = range(150, 250)
>>> xs = map(lambda n: tuple(range(n, n + 10)), xs)
>>> ys = map(lambda n: tuple(range(n, n + 10)), ys)

>>> def profile_pairing():
...     list(izip_pairs(xs, ys, lambda x, y: cmp(x[:4], y[:4])))
...
>>> def profile_keying():
...     list(izip_keys(xs, ys, lambda v: v[:4]))
...

>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> Timer(profile_pairing).timeit(1000)
0.575916051864624
>>> Timer(profile_keying).timeit(1000)
0.39961695671081543

>>> xs = map(lambda n: tuple(range(n, n + 10)), range(1000, 2000))
>>> ys = map(lambda n: tuple(range(n, n + 10)), range(1500, 2500))
>>> Timer(profile_pairing).timeit(100)
0.5289111137390137
>>> Timer(profile_keying).timeit(100)
0.4951910972595215

>>> xs = map(lambda n: tuple(range(n, n + 10)), range(10000, 20000))
>>> ys = map(lambda n: tuple(range(n, n + 10)), range(15000, 25000))
>>> Timer(profile_pairing).timeit(10)
0.6034290790557861
>>> Timer(profile_keying).timeit(10)
0.9461970329284668

>>> xs = map(lambda n: tuple(range(n, n + 10)), range(100000, 200000))
>>> ys = map(lambda n: tuple(range(n, n + 10)), range(150000, 250000))
>>> Timer(profile_pairing).timeit(1)
0.6421248912811279
>>> Timer(profile_keying).timeit(1)
1.253270149230957
```

(Note: Using `deque`* instead of `list(reverse(...))` was 1% faster across all cases. *see few edits back)

Comment: Same comment as for @thg435: why not use a simple list and pop?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I guess I initially started off using `iter()` & `next()` and didn't think to look much further after finding out about `deque`.  I'd reselect this wiki as the most likely answer but can't for 2 days because it's my own post.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is similar to what you already have:

```
from collections import deque

def pairs(xs, ys):
    xs = deque(sorted(xs))
    ys = deque(sorted(ys))

    while xs and ys:
        c = cmp(xs[0], ys[0])
        if c == 0:
            yield xs.popleft(), ys.popleft()
        elif c < 0:
            yield xs.popleft(), None
        else: # c > 0:
            yield None, ys.popleft()

    for x in xs: yield x, None
    for y in ys: yield None, y


xs = [1, 2, 5, 6]
ys = [2, 3, 4, 5]        
print list(pairs(xs, ys))
# [(1, None), (2, 2), (None, 3), (None, 4), (5, 5), (6, None)]
```

Comment: Actually, I never thought to use a `deque`.  I was using `iter()` and `next()` so using `deque` and `.popleft()` as you've suggested gets rid of bulk of the code that went to `try: .. except StopIteration:` and manually keeping track of exhaustion.

Comment: It seems to me that a simple list, instead of a deque, would do. What is the purpose of using a deque with popleft when a list with pop, could be used?

Comment: @EOL: there's no particular purpose, just thought it would be cleaner this way. Feel free to add your version to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
As = set([1, 2, 5, 6])
Bs = set([2, 3, 4, 5])
values = [(a, a) if a in Bs else (a, None) for a in As] + [(None, b) for b in Bs if b not in As]
>>> values
[(1, None), (2, 2), (5, 5), (6, None), (None, 3), (None, 4)]
```

or using sets:

```
>>> values = [(a, a) for a in As.intersection(Bs)] + [(a, None) for a in As - Bs] + [(None, b) for b in Bs - As]
>>> values
[(2, 2), (5, 5), (1, None), (6, None), (None, 3), (None, 4)]
>>>
```

> I'm not worried about duplicates in As or Bs as there won't be any.

so making then sets gives near constant lookup time.

> The ordering of Rs is unimportant.

so we can check A then simply check B :)

I don't know if this is right, this is just from the top of my head, if it has issues I aplogise.

**UPDATE**
this is a bit more challenging, being that we can't hash it we are basically stuck with O(n**2) sorry :(

I tried to make it as optimal as possible.

```
As = [1, 2, 5, 6]
Bs = [2, 3, 4, 5]

indicies_a, indicies_b, values = [], [], []
for index_a, a in enumerate(As):
    for index_b, b in enumerate(Bs):
        if cmp(a, b) == 0:
            values.append((a, b))
            indicies_a.append(index_a) 
            indicies_b.append(index_b)

values += [(As[index], None) for index in set(range(len(As))) - set(indicies_a)] + [(None, Bs[index]) for index in set(range(len(Bs))) - set(indicies_b)]

>>> values
[(2, 2), (5, 5), (1, None), (6, None), (None, 3), (None, 4)]
>>>
```

Sorry I couldn't come up with a more concise version, tried my vest best to make it as fast possible.

Comment: Thanks.  Your example is interesting and certainly minimalistic, but it doesn't meet the `cmp` part of the question, probably because I failed to make it clear why this is required.  I'll update the question with what I wrote to jamylak's answer.

Comment: @antak sorry about that, `__contains__` within lists though not sets actually call `cmp` if the object has it implemented, being that you have tuples it isn't much help here, I came up with another solution, it isn't as concise but I tried making at as efficient as possible.

Comment: The tests that you make in list comprehensions are already implemented as set operations, in Python (set intersection and set difference).

Comment: @EOL not sure what you mean, please clarify, also according the OP we can't really used sets directly, since his data isn't hash-able ...

Comment: @EOL ok I've added it though Im not sure if its any faster those operations are all linear, so thats 3 linear operations vs 2 for my previous solution ...

Comment: @samy.vilar: You are right, my bad: sets are not useable, as per the edit to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this doesn't take into account the `cmp()` operation, but hopefully it helps a bit.

```
>>> As = [1, 2, 5, 6]
>>> Bs = [2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> result = []
>>> for n in set(As + Bs):
...     result.append((n if n in As else None, n if n in Bs else None))
...
>>> result
[(1, None), (2, 2), (None, 3), (None, 4), (5, 5), (6, None)]
>>>
```

Same thing as a list comp:

```
>>> result = [ (n if n in As else None, n if n in Bs else None) for n in set(As + Bs)]
>>> result
[(1, None), (2, 2), (None, 3), (None, 4), (5, 5), (6, None)]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I like the way your code has symmetry and the one-liner was easy for me to understand.  It doesn't satisfy the `cmp()` part (even if I did change the `if n ..` part because of the `set(As + Bs)` part--and I can't imagine how I could do it with a good time complexity) but your solution makes me wonder that I could just get rid of `cmp()` and change it to something that produces hashable key elements, thereby making it possible to use this solution.

Comment: Edit: Binary searches could make the whole thing more or less work in the current form I suppose..

Comment: Whoops, I missed the bit how it muddles the instances around.  I've given up trying to change it so that it's viable.

Comment: Searches in lists with the in operator are slow. Using sets instead would be faster.

Comment: PS: … but using sets is precluded, here, as per the edit to the question (so the `for n in set(…)` cannot actually not be used).

Answer (score 1):

```
([(i,j) for i in As for j in Bs if cmp(i,j) == 0] +
[(i,None) for i in As if all(cmp(i,j) !=0 for j in Bs)] +
[(None, j) for j in Bs if all(cmp(i,j) !=0 for i in As)])
```

however, the time complexity will be n^2 because we could not tell whether an element is larger than the other one according to your description.

Comment: You're right, I meant that cmp() would be like the builtin in returning -1, 0, and +1, but I didn't make that explicit.  I like the way you've built a one-liner even with this constraint.